# How can i change label text from different class (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, class, button, label

How can i change label text in different class? Now, i using this scripts but label not changed.

**Winform script:**

```
public partial class buildEditor : Form
{
    ChangeTextForMaxSkill skill = new ChangeTextForMaxSkill(this);

    public buildEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label maxSkillPoint = new Label();
        maxSkillPoint.AutoSize = true;
        maxSkillPoint.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        maxSkillPoint.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
        maxSkillPoint.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(193)))), ((int)(((byte)(196)))), ((int)(((byte)(181)))));
        maxSkillPoint.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(528, 687);
        maxSkillPoint.Name = "maxSkillPoint";
        maxSkillPoint.Text = UniqueValue.spentSkillPoints.ToString();
        maxSkillPoint.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(maxSkillPoint);
    }

    public void maxSkillPoint_TextChanged(Form formInstance, string labelName)
    {
        // Get reference to the label
        var label = formInstance.Controls.Find(labelName, true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (null != label && label is Label)
        {
            (label as Label).Text = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

I created next class which will be change text for maxSkillPoint label, but its dont work.

```
public class ChangeTextForMaxSkill()
{
    Button button = new Button();

    public ChangeTextForMaxSkill()
    {
        button.Click += new EventHandler(changeText);
    }

    private void changeText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get reference to the label
        var buildEditor = new buildEditor();
        buildEditor.maxSkillPoint_TextChanged(buildEditor, "maxSkillPoint");
    }
}
```

**Debug for find control:**

```
buildEditor {test.buildEditor, Text: test}  test.buildEditor
this    {test.ChangeTextForMaxSkill}    test.ChangeTextForMaxSkill
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Does it throw an Exception? Does the text simply not get changed?

Comment: yep, text for label not changed on "test"

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if `label` winds up being null after your call to `Find`?

Comment: i added debug up to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the text of the local button instance. What you want is to get a reference to the original button first.
Attach to that button the event and change there the string.

Use this:

```
public class ChangeTextForMaxSkill
{
    buildEditor editor;

    public ChangeTextForMaxSkill(buildEditor editor) // inject reference to form
    {
        this.editor = editor;
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Click += new EventHandler(changeText);
        form.Controls.Add(button);
    }

    private void changeText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get reference to the label
        editor.maxSkillPoint_TextChanged(editor, "maxSkillPoint");
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my first post. Your script have errors for me.

Because i using this in buildEditor forms:
ChangeTextForMaxSkill skill = new ChangeTextForMaxSkill(); (for some next functions)

Comment: Then just use `new ChangeTextForMaxSkill(this);` instead.

Comment: I edited again my first post and erros is this:

Error 1 Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

Comment: Put the line at the end of the constructor after `this.Controls.Add(maxSkillPoint);`